# DebugPrintToFile Function to Debug kernel driver on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver

Is there something like a DebugPrintToFile function that will save variable's value to a log file, in order to debug kernel driver code.

Similar to debugprint but with an actual file.

Setting up 2 PCs to debug driver is too complex for me.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution to this problem, was using DebugView
and adding DbgPrint to the driver code when needed.
`DbgPrint("status %d.\n", RtlNtStatusToDosError(status));`